# Is it possible for an Elasticsearch index to have a primary key comprised of multiple fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I have a multi-tenant system, whereby each tenant gets their own Mongo database within a MongoDB deployment.

However for elastic search indexing, this all goes into one elastic instance via Mongoosastic, tagged with a TenantDB to keep data separated when searching.

Currently we have some of the same _id's reused across the multiple databases in test data for various config collections(Different document content, same _id), however this is causing a problem when syncing to elastic as although they're in separate databases when they come into elastic with the same Type and ID one of them gets dropped.

Is it possible to specify both the ID and TenantDB as the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: You can search for multiple index in Elasticsearch. But, If you can not separate your index for database, you can follow like below method.  While syncing your data to elasticsearch, use a pattern to create elastic document _id. For example, from mongoDb1 use `mdb1_{mongo_id}`, from mongoDb2 use `mdb2_{mongo_id}` , etc. This will be unique your _ids if you have not same id in same mongo database.

Solution 2: Separate your index.